# update_or_create with ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 models, like this:

```
class Subs(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Subs)
```

I need to update tags field - add new values.
How can I update instance of Users with update_or_create method?

For example:

```
tag_1 = Subs.object.get(pk=1)
Users.objects.update_or_create(name='test_user', tags=tag_1)
```

If user 'test_user' doesn't exist, it must be created, or if it exists tag_1 must be added to this user.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible to add `tags` in `update_or_create` because `tags` is a `ManyToManyField` and therefore involves an intermediate table for database queries.

You can however do it in two lines using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
user = Users.objects.get_or_create(name='test_user')
user.tags.add(tag_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

user, created = Users.objects.get_or_create(name='test_user')

user.tags.add(tag_1)

get_or_create return tuple

Comment: user, created = Users.objects.get_or_create(name='test_user')
user.tags.add(tag_1)

get_or_create return tuple

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).